# Why do I get a FileNotFoundError for some Windows filepaths but not others?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that will launch programs for me, but some programs python just won't find. I've been using the technique of:

```
if action == "Powerpoint":
    import os
    os.startfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.exe")
```

And this has worked for all of my other programs but this one just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes in [string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) are special:

> [String literals] can be enclosed in matching single quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`)...The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

The `\r` in your string:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.exe"
                                        ^^
```

is being interpreted as an escape sequence meaning carriage return, not a literal backslash followed by a literal "r".

You should use a raw string so backslashes aren't interpreted as escape sequences:

```
r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks man, I had no idea you could do that. It fixed the whole problem.